# How do I remove dashes and whitespace using regex?

Tags: java, regex

I'm having trouble removing dashes and whitespace from my code. For ex: I want J.D Smith Company to just be JDSmith or Mike-Jones Inc to just be MikeJones. Below is the code that I currently have.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\.$|,|;|'|-|\\s|-]|\\b(\\s|LLC|Company|Incorporated|Co|Manufacturer|The|Limited|Ltd|Inc|Chemicals|Solutions|-\\s)\\b", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(dncMfgName.getStringCellValue());
String name = m.replaceAll("");
```

The words like LLC and Inc seem to be gone but the algorithm seems to be tripped up by spaces. Apologies for any superfluous code, I am still a bit new to this!

Comment: Don't use `|` inside a `[]` character class, unless you want to match the `|` character. --- Why do you have `-` in there twice? --- You do know that `-` has special meaning in a `[]` character class, right? So you need to escape it (or put it first or last). --- `.` does not have special meaning in a `[]` character class, so no need to escape it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Don't use `|` inside a `[]` character class, unless you want to match the `|` character.
- No need to have `-` in there twice.
- `-` has special meaning in a `[]` character class, so you need to escape it (or put it first or last).
- `.` does not have special meaning in a `[]` character class, so no need to escape it.
- `\s` matches all whitespace, but you don't want to replace linebreaks, so use `\h` instead.
- No need to match `\s` or `-` in the second half of the regex (already covered in first half).

All in all, that means:

```regex
[\h.$,;'-]|\b(?:LLC|Company|Incorporated|Co|Manufacturer|The|Limited|Ltd|Inc|Chemicals|Solutions)\b
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/4k7i7C/1).